# CDI bean that starts with the application

Tags: java, tomcat, cdi

Is there any way to startup a CDI Bean with the application?

I have this bean:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Named
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private Helper helper;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        helper.doThings();
    }

}
```

I would like that this bean to start with the app, on deploy.

I'm using the weld-servlet and tomcat7:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${weld-servlet.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
public void startup(@Observes @Initialized 
(ApplicationScoped.class) Object context){
    //your code here
}
```

That will ensure the method is executed at startup, and start your bean.

Or you can use OmniFaces `@Eager` annotation.

Comment: @Henrique Santiago replace the method annotated with `@PostConstruct` in your code with it.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your tomcat7 variant supports CDI (See [tomcat version comparison](http://tomee.apache.org/comparison.html))
Then,

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class MyBean {
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        // place your initialization code here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, `@Singleton` is an EJB annotation, not CDI. As such it won't kick in with just servlets.

Comment: If you check the tomcat version comparison url I shared, you'll see that my answer is accurate.